# How to send request to an asmx webservice

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using a `asmx` webserivce. But I don't know how to send a request.
My webservice:

http://188.75.80.115:83/WebService1.asmx?op=getKey

Can I use `fetch`?

Another problem is response. The response of this web service is:

```
<databack xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<Status>true</Status>
<Error/>
<Data>4yhj6mXwKTkkz4MJjaNfS/BRK8cx6/gH</Data>
</databack>
```

I think I should use `react-native-xml2js`. is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Javascript then you can use the following code to send a request to your Webservice.

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Ajax.asmx/{your-service-function}",
        data: JSON.stringify({ firstParam: 'value'}),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    });
```

or, if you are using React, use the following code
for more

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: 'yourValue',
    secondParam: 'yourOtherValue'
    })
}).then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJson) => {
    // response in responseJson
}).catch((error) => {
    //handle your error
});
```

This link would also help you [Fetch](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html)

Comment: I think `fetch` does't work for `asmx`. Please try it out.